# Dynamically select the subreport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, subreport

I have 5 subreports in my main report.
Now my requirement is based on selection from UI i need to display combinations of reports.
say:
Main.jrxml
sub1.jrxml
sub2.jrxml
sub3.hrxml

if user wants sub1 and sub3 in main how do i hide sub2?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the sub-reports by applying "Print When Expression" property of the report.