# Display subreport with empty db-set

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I want to display a single subreport (and only this specific one, not the others), even if the sql does not retrieve any dataset from the db. Is there some tag to use in the jrxml to do so?
Maybe something like

```
PrintWhenExpression
```

or something else?

Comment: You can view this posts: [Blank subreport in Jasper report](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7954730/876298), [Hide or show Subreport](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15557440/876298), [Jasper reporting - sub report's return value is null](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19384421/876298), [Remove blank page generated by JasperReports: how to hide the empty subreport?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19432751/876298), [Dynamically select the subreport](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15034447/876298). The search on *SO* is really good thing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "When No Data Type" report property and "No Data" band.